# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function test()

Tags: php, functions

So I'm having an issue where I'm getting a 'Undefined function' response and I can't seem to figure out why and how to target it.

**Relative path to the shortcode file**: htdocs/wp-content/mu-plugins/s/shortcodes/profile.php
[image]

**Relative path to the profile card**: htdocs/wp-content/mu-plugins/s/templates/people-card.php
- (This is where I have some HTML)

---

What I'd like to achieve:

- Apply the shortcode to the page then have the shortcode function call the profile-card.php page and grab all the content within and display it.

So are the very end, the shortcode will show the 'profile-card.php' page.

**The code I have inside shortcodes/profile.php**:

```
function clearline_func() {
    test();
}
add_shortcode('test', 'clearline_func');
```

I'm getting a `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function test()` error.

Comment: Of course you are. You're using `test();`, but that function doesn't exist. What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: @JacobPeattie, so I had a test function within the `profile-card.php` directly but I wasn't getting any returns.

What's the best method to include all content from `profile-card.php` and use that shortcode to show it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what your `test()` function is meant to achieve, or if you've even defined it, but yes if you haven't defined it then it's undefined.

In reference to your question: "What's the best method to include all content from profile-card.php and use that shortcode to show it?" The answer is actually in your question, i.e. the best method to include it is to include it, literally. If you haven't included that PHP file, and your `test()` function is actually defined in there, then that's why it's undefined, because that file was never included.

Granted, I'm somewhat extrapolating what I think you're trying to do based on the information provided, but try this:

```
include(__DIR__.'/profile-card.php');
function clearline_func() {
    return test();
}
add_shortcode('test', 'clearline_func');
```

Or if your profile-card.php file is directly producing output, you can capture the output in a variable and then return it from the shortcode callback function. A shortcode callback function should not produce any output, it should always return the desired output.

Something like this:

```
function clearline_func(){
    ob_start();
    include(__DIR__.'/profile-card.php');
    test(); //-> You can call your test function here or just call it in the included php file.
    $output = ob_get_clean();
    return $output;
}
add_shortcode('test', 'clearline_func');
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch @KFish, this works like a charm!

Comment: No problem, glad it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

You should have the desired code defined within your `clearline_func` function like this:

```
function clearline_func() {
    //copy & paste the profile-card.php code here
}
add_shortcode('test', 'clearline_func');
```

If you need to keep the profile-card.php file and want to avoid duplicate code then you should use PHP `include()` to call the file as @KFish suggested above.

Comment: Thanks @Tom! I just wanted to keep it clean and separate the profile-card file with the shortcode since I'll be building out a HTML template there.